# Verilog variables updated only when assigned as an output

Tags: led, digital-logic, fpga, verilog

I am facing a strange issue, and I am not sure what is going on here:

```
assign output_data = {3'b000, cmd_state[1:0], w_data[2:0]};
```

Where last 5-bits of output data are assigned to physical LEDs in ice40 stick FPGA. I am using above line in a large Verilog program.
When I test the code I can see `cmd_state` and `w_data` bits on LEDs.
But, if I change above line to:

```
assign output_data = {3'b000, w_data[4:0]};
```

I get no updates on the LEDs. Just to emphasise in first case I get LEDs reflecting some update for w[2:0] bits but in second case where w[4:0] bits are reflected on LEDs I see no updates on LEDs. Ideally I should get same updates for w_data[2:0] in both cases. I am not sure why this happens.

Could anyone give me an insight what is going on here?

Comment: Whatever the problem is it's not visible in the lines of code you've posted. `out_data[2:0]` are identical in both cases. The problem is somewhere else you haven't shown.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 lines of Verilog code will be different when the 2 bits `cmd_state[1:0]` are **not** equal to the 2 bits `w_data[4:3]`.

For example, the 1st line of code assigns the 5 LSBs of `output_data` as follows:

```
output_data[4] = cmd_state[1]
output_data[3] = cmd_state[0]
output_data[2] = w_data[2]
output_data[1] = w_data[1]
output_data[0] = w_data[0]
```

The 2nd line of code makes different assignments for some of the bits, which would give you the different results you are seeing.

You need to check how `output_data` is used to drive the LEDs.  You must have intervening logic between the `output_data` signal and the LEDs.

Comment: I understand that perfectly. But w_data[2:0] outputs should be reflected on LEDs in same way in both cases. But I only get output LEDs reflecting w_data[2:0] in first case but not in second case.

Comment: @NickaS: I agree, but that is not what your question asked.  We can't see how the output drives the leds.  Answer updated.

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope its clear now

Comment: @NickaS: No, it is not clear yet.  As my answer says, you need to show us how the leds are connected to output data.  Post your code as a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run a sim if you want more specifc help.